# Bootstrap carousel and column will not stay next to each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

**Goal:**
I would like to create a bootstrap row where there is a carousel on the left and text blocks on the right. I have labeled these "Left Column" and "Right Column" respectively within the HTML comments.

**Problem:**
I'm not able to get the carousel and text to stay in columns. Instead, they stack on top of each other, with the carousel on top and the next column going below it.

**Context:**
I've tried a few different things by moving around divs and creating new ones. I've already tried to remove the flex CSS styling and I've tried to remove all padding and margins. I've reviewed several stack overflow questions that seemed similar, but none of the problems seems similar to mine or the suggestions do not help.

It does not appear that there is anything within the main CSS that is causing this issue, because I am able to get other columns and rows to work correctly on the same page. However, I'm adding it here just in case with a screenshot.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <!-- Left Column Start -->
            <div class="col-6" id="carousel-contain">
                <div id="plantCarousel" class="carousel slide col-6" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        {% for image in plant.plant_images.all %}
                            {% if forloop.first %}
                                <li data-target="#plantCarousel" data-slide-to="{{forloop.counter0}}" class="active"></li>
                            {% else %}
                                <li data-target="#plantCarousel" data-slide-to="{{forloop.counter0}}"></li>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                      <li data-target="#plantCarousel"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        {% for image in plant.plant_images.all %}
                            {% if forloop.first %}
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            {% else %}
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                            {% endif %}
                                <img src="{{ image.images.url }}" alt="{{ plant.name }}">
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                
                        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#plantCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#plantCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Left Column Ends -->

            <!-- Right Column Start -->
            <div class="col-6">
                <p> <b>Latin Name: </b>{{ plant.latin_name }} </p>
                <br>
                <p><b>Description: </b></p>
                <p> {{ plant.description }} </p>
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>
            <!-- Right Column Ends --> 
    
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  html {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

body {
  margin-bottom: 60px; /* Margin bottom by footer height */
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
}

.pricing-header {
  max-width: 700px;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px; /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

**How it appears on the page:**
[image: screenshot of bootstrap carousel not appearing to the left of the second column]

Comment: which text block you talking about?

Comment: Its the text block that says "Latin Name" and "Description" in it.

I labeled the text block "Right Column" within the HTML comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around even further, I discovered that I accidentally added an extra `</div>` which caused my row to end before the right column could be added into the row.